# Proving Sylow theorems without using group actions

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, sylow-theory

Most of the proofs of Sylow theorems involves groups actions in some way as below:

[Sylow theorems - wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Proof_of_the_Sylow_theorems)

There is a thread for them here, too:
[Proofs of Sylow theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161700/proofs-of-sylow-theorems).

However, I would like to see proofs of these 3 theorems without using group actions. Somehow, they do not seem *natural* to me. If there is a reason for defining group actions, using orbits & stabilizers that I do not know, I would like to know it.

Comment: As I recall, Herstein offers three proofs of the first Sylow theorem in Topics in Algebra. The first of the three was combinatorial. I don't recall if it used group actions or not, and I don't have the book on hand, but that is the first that comes to mind.

Comment: I checked the proofs of Herstein and they are very good, thanks.

Comment: One of the Sylow theorems says that all Sylow subgroups are conjugate, which is logically equivalent to saying that there is a single orbit of the the conjugation action of $G$ on the set of Sylow subgroups. So the statement involves a group action and it does not make much sense to ask for a proof that does not involve group actions. It's like asking a proof that does not use subgroups.

Comment: Oh, this is the reason that I could not realize. Thanks!